# Has anyone heard of this strange bug with the standard Windows message box?

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, messagebox

Years ago, I was messing around with Visual Basic and I discovered a bug with the `MsgBox` function. I tried searching for it, but nobody had ever said anything about it. It's not just with Visual Basic though; it's with anything that uses the standard Windows `MessageBox` API call.

The bug is triggered when the title text has more than one character, and the first character is a lowercase 'y' with an umlaut ('ÿ'). What's so special about this character? It almost definitely not the character itself, but rather its ASCII value that's special. 'ÿ' is character 255 (0xFF), meaning it's the highest value that can be stored in an unsigned byte, and all its bits are set to 1.

What does this bug do? Well, there are two different possibilities, which depend on the number of characters in the title text. If there are an even number of characters (unless it's 2) in the title text, no message box appears, and you just hear the alert sound. If there are two characters in the title text, or any odd number other than 1 (in which case the bug wouldn't be triggered)...then *this* happens:

[image: It's in the "System" font (as used in Windows 3.1.)]

And that's not all--the message will also be truncated to one line. It seems like the kind of bug that would occur in at least one semi-high-profile incident, considering how often this API call is used. Are there any reports of this on the Internet, or anything showing what could cause it? Maybe it's a Unicode-related glitch, like that "bush hid the facts" glitch in Notepad?

I made a program in case you want to play around with this; [download it here](http://bit.ly/15ZS47T).

Alternatively, copy the following into Notepad, save it with a `.vbs` extension, and double-click it to display the dialog box seen above:

```
MsgBox "Windows 3.1 font, anyone?", 0, "ÿ ODD NUMBER!"
```

Or for a different font:

```
MsgBox "I CAN HAS CHEEZBURGER?", 0, "ÿ HImpact"
```

**EDIT:** It seems that if the first *four* characters are `ÿ`'s, it doesn't ever display the message, even if there's an odd number of characters.

Comment: Instead of asking us to download programs with little secrets, why don't you just show the code?

Comment: I think this is actually better known than you'd think. I recall taking a course on x86 ASM using MASM on Windows 2000 and encountering this very same behavior by improperly initializing the title string. Half the class encountered this, and thought they were mistakenly using the Win16 API (yeah, WoW32 still existed back then) :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code is included. It's just a little Easter egg I put in.

Comment: Off site downloads with 20 files are no good. Show a 20 line SSCCE in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of this program. The bug is described in the OP; you literally only need one line of code to do it. (Well, depending on what programming language you use.) All it involves is calling a specific function with specific arguments described exactly in the question. For example (C#): `MessageBox.Show("Windows 3.1 font, anyone?", "ÿ ODD NUMBER!")` Or classic VB: `MsgBox "Windows 3.1 font, anyone?", 0, "ÿ ODD NUMBER!"` All the program does is let you fill in the title and text, and easily type the `ÿ` character.

Comment: So provide in the question a complete program that we can run. Please can you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strange bug. I suspect the symptoms are the result of the way the `MessageBox()` actually displays the dialog.

Internally, `MessageBox()` [builds a dialog template dynamically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/29/412577.aspx). If you look at the description of a [`DLGTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure you'll find the following nugget of information:

> In a standard template for a dialog box, the DLGTEMPLATE structure is
>   always immediately followed by three variable-length arrays that
>   specify the menu, class, and title for the dialog box. When the
>   DS_SETFONT style is specified, these arrays are also followed by a
>   16-bit value specifying point size and another variable-length array
>   specifying a typeface name.

So, the in-memory layout of a dialog template has the font specification immediately following the dialog box title.

Visual Basic does not use Unicode and so the function you're calling is actually `MessageBoxA()`. This is simply a thunk that converts the passed-in strings from multibyte to Unicode and then calls `MessageBoxW()`.

I believe what's happening is that, for some reason, the conversion of that string from multibyte to Unicode is either going wrong, or returning a spurious length value. This has the knock-on effect, when the dialog template is built in memory, of corrupting the memory immediately following the title string - which, as we know, is the font specification.

Comment: This was my first thought as well. It would be interesting to know if this happens in non-NT versions of Windows (e.g. 95, 98), which will natively use ANSI.

Comment: Nope, it's not a multibyte to wide char issue. The same behaviour occurs when you call MessageBoxW.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug with dialog templates generally.  It is not a message box bug as such.

For example, in Visual Studio create the default win32 application.  In the .rc file, change the caption in the template for the about box from

```
CAPTION "About sampleapp"
```

to

```
CAPTION "ÿT"
```

and the bug will manifest itself when you display the about box.

In the [DLGTEMPLATEEX documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) note that the menu and class name have type `sz_Or_Ord` which means either a null-terminated string or `0xFFFF` followed by a single word resource identifier.

Windows incorrectly applies a similar scheme to the dialog title: if the first character is `0xFF` then it treats the title as being two WORDs long, but only when it is trying to locate the font information.  When it is displaying the title it correctly treats the title as a string.

In other words, Windows is looking for the font information inside the title string.  In most case this won't specify a valid font, so Windows defaults to the system font.

To prove this, I constructed a dialog template in memory ([based on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/29/412577.aspx)).  Once this was working I deleted the code that writes the font information to the template and used the dialog title "ÿa\xd\x200\x21SimSun".  This displays the dialog in italic SimSun because windows is reading the font information from the title string.

This bug is likely a hangover from 16-bit Windows, where (I guess) 0xFF was used as the resource ID marker.